# Larave conditional aggregation to get multiple sum of amount

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sum, aggregate-functions

Hope all is well.

Anyone can tell me how can I get to run this SQL query in a the right way in Laravel?

Controller:

```
     $data=DB::raw("SELECT name as 'name' FROM invoices WHERE country='$country';
            SELECT SUM(amount) as 'income' FROM invoices WHERE (country='$country' AND type='income');
            SELECT SUM(amount) as 'outcome' FROM invoices WHERE (country='$country' AND type='outcome')")
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->get();

        return view('accounting.accounts')
        ->with('accounts',$data);
```

I expect to use it in my view as follows:

```
@foreach($accounts as $account)
       <tr>
        <th>{{$account->name}}</th>
        <td>{{$account->income}}</td>
        <td>{{$account->outcome}}</td>
       </tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm new to Laravel, I would appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: _how can I get to run this SQL query in a the right way?_ That is, you want to write this request in Eloquent, right ?

Comment: Eloquent or raw, I just need to retrive the requested data. It doesnt seem to work the way I posted it

Comment: It won't work the way you posted it. You've got three separate queries with no discernible link between them. It might be possible to extract the data you want, but wit your a schema it's impossible to see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want an agrregated query with conditional sum of amount for each user within a specific country.
In pure SQL it can done using `CASE` statements as

```
select  name,
        sum(case when type='income' then amount else 0 end) as income,
        sum(case when type='outcome' then amount else 0 end) as outcome
from invoices
where country = :country
group by name
order by name
```

In query builder it can be tranformed as

```
$accounts= DB::table("invoices")
            ->where("country", $country)
            ->select([ "name",
                        DB::raw("sum(case when type='income' then amount else 0 end) as income"),
                        DB::raw("sum(case when type='outcome' then amount else 0 end) as outcome")
                    ])
            ->groupBy("name")
            ->orderBy("name")
            ->get();
```